# azcopy will not stay open, wants cmd.exe

Tags: azcopy

I downloaded the azcopy folder and unzipped it onto my computer. When I open it it says "You need to open cmd.exe and run it from there" and then it closes the screen within a few seconds. I've tried searching this line and come up with nothing... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much thanks for your answer! It all comes down to the fact that I thought I was to run azcopy by opening that file - didn't realize I had to run it on a command prompt app. But that still may not have worked without your code to get azcopy working on my command prompt app.

Thanks for taking the time to help a newby :)

Comment: If that could help you, you could accept it as the answer. If you don't know how to do it you could follow this.https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to use CMD to change the directory to the azcopy folder then run the azcopy command.

[image]

[image]

The other way is to add the folder path to the Environment Variable `PATH`.

[image]